# Performance when querying from View vs from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question TLDR:** Given two identical datasets, one is stored as a view and the other is stored as a table,  does querying off the view result in longer run-time than querying off the table?  Specific details might be needed, but I was wondering what the general practice rule is.

**Background:**
I'm in a work environment that utilizes SQL Server for analytical and data science purposes.  Lately we've been plagued with slower-than-usual processing speeds and we think it has to do with users writing expensive queries and maybe the use of a view to compile datasets from 12 monthly tables.  The use of this view and the practice of commonly querying off this view may be a source of our problems.

**Question Description:**  Lets say I have a view called [myView] that compiles data from 12 monthly tables.  I also have a table called [myTable] that is compiled from the same 12 monthly tables.  Reporting wise, [myView] and [myTable] are identical.   **IS querying off [myTable] less expensive than querying off [myView]?**

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524645/3179169

Comment: Data isn't stored on a `VIEW`; "A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query. ". Querying from a `VIEW` and directly from the table with perform identically, if the `SELECT` statement is the same as that in the `VIEW`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have the table data populated with the query from the view, the performance will be better from the table. View doesn't save data so it will have to compute the results every time. The difference in performance might be very small depending on the complexity of the query, changing data or caching that will depend on the usage of the table or view.

Comment: @clinomaniac how can you say that an identical query would be slower with a view? That simply is not true.

Comment: Are you by chance indulging in nested views? Meaning you have created a view that part of the query in that view references another view?

Comment: @SeanLange My understanding was that the table was being treated as a materialized view which means the calculation part has been done and will not be computed again. The first line in the question says that the dataset is the same. One is a view, one is a table so a view will need to do the computations when you do a `SELECT` on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of Tables vs. Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524550/performance-of-tables-vs-views)

Comment: In general, the single table would be faster.  There are exceptions of course, but that is a useful starting point.

Comment: Jumping to conclusions is not an effective means to diagnose or improve anything. The fact that you have "monthly" tables suggests you have schema problems which your query writers struggle to overcome. Why now? You've reached the tipping point with regard to scaling? And since you used the term "lately", perhaps something has recently changed that is causing or contributing to the issue. The first step is to examine the execution plan.